# Attempting to remove initial section of mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm attempting to remove an initial section of an mp4 file.  When running the command this results:

```
ffmpeg -i clip-1.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -ss 0 -t 00:43:00 OUTFILE.mp4

    [mp4 @ 0x204d9a0] Malformed AAC bitstream detected: use the audio bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc' to fix it ('-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc' option with ffmpeg)
    av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted
    [mp4 @ 0x204d9a0] Malformed AAC bitstream detected: use the audio bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc' to fix it ('-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc' option with ffmpeg)
    frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:01.98 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s    
    video:29kB audio:6kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
    Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what the message says: Use the `-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc` option on your `ffmpeg` command:

```
fmpeg -i clip-1.mp4 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -acodec copy -vcodec copy -ss 0 -t 00:43:00 OUTFILE.mp4
```

Comment: On minor tweak - I had to use -ss 00:43:00 and remove the -t parameter in order to chop off the first 43 minutes.